# JavaScript Split Value

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following code:

```
var format_time="28-06-12 9:30:50";
var my_time_array=format_time.split(":");
alert(my_time_array[0]); // alerts 28-06-12 9
alert(my_time_array[1]); // alerts 30
alert(my_time_array[2]); // alerts 50
```

The first alert incorrectly displays "28-06-12 9", when I only want it to display "9".
Additionally, if format_time="28-06-12 10:30:50", then I would want it to display "10".

I can't seem to work it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split by space first:

```
var my_time_array=format_time.split(" ")[1].split(":");
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var hour = my_time_array[0].split(" ");
alert(hour[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var format_time="28-06-12 9:30:50"; 
var my_time_array=format_time.split(" "); 
var my_time_array2=my_time_array[1].split(":"); 

alert(my_time_array2[0]); // alerts 9 
alert(my_time_array2[1]); // alerts 30 
alert(my_time_array2[2]); // alerts 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var format_time="28-06-12 9:30:50"; 
var my_time_array1=format_time.split(" "); //Split on space. 
var my_time_array=my_time_array1[1].split(":"); //now split the time part.
alert(my_time_array[0]); // alerts 28-06-12 9 
alert(my_time_array[1]); // alerts 30 
alert(my_time_array[2]); // alerts 50
```